# NSFetchedResuktsController - Cache causing a crash?

Tags: ios, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have an NSFetchedResultsController with a static request that never changes. If the previous number of records was 0 (last time the fetchedResultscontroller was used), and then somewhere else (While user is on another viewController) a new record gets added to core data that would be a part of the request, next time I load the page I get a crash.

This crash only happens when the previous number of records retrieved from fetchedResultsController were 0.

```
CoreData: error: Serious application error.  Exception was caught during Core Data change processing.  This is usually a bug within an observer of NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification.  *** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array with userInfo (null)
2014-11-26 13:55:50.772 Company[47714:613] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'


_fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:self.fetchRequest
                                                                    managedObjectContext:context
                                                                      sectionNameKeyPath:self.sectionNameKeyPath
                                                                               cacheName:self.fetchedResultsControllerCacheName];
```

Any solution to this?

Comment: Does it happen when caching is disabled? Can yo post the code please?

Comment: It only happens when I set a cache name on the fetched results controller.

Comment: Can you also add the part where the FRC is being used? Probably DataSource of some kind

Comment: Are you using the FRC delegate methods?  When you say "next time I load the page" - is that using an existing instance of the FRC, or creating a new one?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have several NSFetchedResultsControllers using the same cache name? I seem to recall that causing some trouble for me. It's also recommended in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsController_Class/)

"If you have multiple fetched results controllers with different configurations (different sort descriptors and so on), you must give each a different cache name."

Comment: No only one fetched results controller with a unique cache name